# A question about asymptotic notations with ln and theta

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

Suppose f is a positive function and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(n) = \infty$.

I need to prove that for a positive function $g(n)$, if $g(n)= \ln( \Theta (f(n)))$, then $g(n)= \Theta(\ln(f(n)))$.

Comment: How is $\Theta$ defined?

Comment: @Karlo/ See the answer to the Q for the def'n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation in asymptotic analysis always makes this a little bit confusing. $\Theta$ represents a class of functions, so "$g(n)=\Theta(\ln(f(n)))$" should really be $g(n)\in \Theta(\ln(f(n)))$. With that in mind, $g(n)=\ln(\Theta(f(n)))$ really means:
$$g(n) = \ln(h(n))$$ for some $h(n)\in \Theta(f(n))$, which by definition means there exist $C_1$ and $C_2$ so that
$$C_1 f(n) < h(n) < C_2 f(n)$$
for all $n \geq N$ for some $N$ large enough.

Given that $\ln(\cdot)$ is monotonically increasing, it follows that
$$\ln(C_1)+\ln(f(n)) = \ln(C_1f(n)) < \ln(h(n))=g(n) < \ln(C_2f(n)) = \ln(C_2)+ \ln(f(n))$$

It is possible that $0<C_1<1$ which would cause the log to be negative, so a bit more care has to be taken than the gut-instinct to assert that "$\ln(f(n))\leq \ln(C_1)+\ln(f(n))$", which is not true in general.

As $f(n) \to \infty$, $\ln(f(n))\to\infty$ so for $N_1$ and $N_2$ sufficiently large,
$$ 0 \leq \ln(C_1) + \tfrac{1}{2}\ln(f(n)),\;n\geq N_1
\quad\text{and}\quad \ln(C_2) \leq \ln(f(n)),\; n\geq N_2$$

So if $n\geq \hat{N} \equiv \max\{N, N_1, N_2\}$, then
\begin{align}
\tfrac{1}{2}\ln(f(n)) &\leq \tfrac{1}{2}\ln(f(n)) + \ln(C_1) + \tfrac{1}{2}\ln(f(n))\\
&= \ln(C_1) + \ln(f(n))
< g(n)\\
&< \ln(C_2)+\ln(f(n)) \leq \ln(f(n)) + \ln(f(n)) = 2\ln(f(n))
\end{align}
hence,
$$ k_1\ln(f(n)) < g(n) < k_2\ln(f(n))$$
for all $n\geq \hat{N}$, (for constants $k_1=\tfrac{1}{2}$ and $k_2=2$) which means that $g(n) \in \Theta(\ln(f(n)))$ by definition.

Comment: Great answer. The asymptotic analysis is as you said a little confusing but now it's clear.